# Libgdx JsonWriter StackOverflowError

Tags: java, json, libgdx, stack-overflow, circular-reference

I'm getting a `StackOverflowError` when trying to write an object to json with `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json`, which is based on [jsonbeans](https://code.google.com/p/jsonbeans/). The object and all objects it references only contain primitive variables like float, boolean, int, etc except for references to a ShapeRenderer. Multiple objects all reference the same ShapeRenderer. There are some circular references (objects both having a reference to each other) but i assume it should be able to handle that.

What could be the cause of these errors? Are the circular references the problem? I can't simply remove them without going back to the drawing board and restructuring major parts of my app.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty$1.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Unknown Source)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonWriter$OutputType.quoteName(JsonWriter.java:174)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonWriter.name(JsonWriter.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonWriter.set(JsonWriter.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeType(Json.java:574)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeObjectStart(Json.java:533)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:491)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:237)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:492)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:237)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:492)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:237)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:492)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:237)
```

This goes on for about 1024 lines:

```
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:492)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeFields(Json.java:237)
```

Not sure whether that's the log limit or the stack limit, i guess the first one.

Comment: Can you try trim down the values you're trying to write into a small example?  You might be able to isolate the specific problem.  I suspect a small example with a circular reference will expose the problem ...

Comment: I removed all circular references and all references to ShapeRenderer. i pass the shaperenderer to the render functions of the objects that need rendering every frame along with some other variables that i used to get directly from the parent object when needed. now the json writer and reader work, but i still don't know why exactly it won't play nice with circular references. it wouldnt be that hard to detect, just store 1 copy of each unique instance at most and reference the rest by ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circular references are the problem. This is a nice [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20562820/1895303):

> I think the best way to address this is, is to probably remove your
>   circular link by re-architeching your data structure in some way,
>   maybe using some sort of map or table instead to link the Entity to
>   the Item.
>
> If you really must keep the circular references, then I'd recommend
>   writing your own parser as simply ignoring the owner on serialization
>   will mean the owner is not returned when the serialized objects are
>   deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances you can also set those references to null just before serializing, and then restore them right after deserializing. For example:

```
class Parent {
    Array<Son> sons;

    public void serialize() {
       clearParents();
       ... serialization code ...
       restoreParents();
    }

    public static Parent deserialize(data) {
        Parent parent = ... deserialization code ...
        parent.restoreParents();
        return parent;
    }

    public void clearParents() {
        for (Son son :sons) {
            son.parent = null;
        }
    }

    public void restoreParents() {
        for (Son son :sons) {
            son.parent = this;
        }
    }

}

class Son {
    Parent parent;

    public Son (Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.sons.add(this);
    }
}
```